# Need help in understanding the inheritance from interface<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit

I am writing integration tests using xUnit for .NET Core 3.0 APIs. While referring to microsoft documentation, I came across below sample code. I am not able to understand

1. syntax of class definition where it is implementing interface. can someone please explain?
2. How dependancy will be injected in the constructor?

```
public class BasicTests: IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup> _factory;

    public BasicTests(WebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("/")]
    [InlineData("/Index")]
    [InlineData("/About")]
    [InlineData("/Privacy")]
    [InlineData("/Contact")]
    public async Task Get_EndpointsReturnSuccessAndCorrectContentType(string url)
    {
        // Arrange
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();

        // Act
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299
        Assert.Equal("text/html; charset=utf-8", 
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: [XUnit IClassFixture](https://blog.somewhatabstract.com/tag/iclassfixture/) please check this post

Comment: There's nothing special about the syntax - it's just a generic intreface. It could be eg `IList<string>`. In this case though, the type parameter is expected to be the *Fixture* that's shared among all tests in a class. Check [Class Fixtures](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#class-fixture) in XUnit's [Shared Context](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context) docs

Comment: `WebApplicationFactory` is a special type of class though - it builds up an entire ASP.NET Core app based on a `Startup` containing mocked services etc, and allows you to call the controller actions through the mocked client created by `CreateClient`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks! another thing i am confused about is how does constructor receive an object of the dependancy? as my test is working fine but i can't figure out what is actually injecting factory instance?

Comment: The *fixture* is the dependency. Read the `Shared Context` article to understand what Fixture means (essentially, something that has to be shared by all tests). In this case the Fixture is a Factory that produces clients to a mocked site. That factory can be used by all test suites that want to test the full ASP.NET Core site

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks again! can you please share the link for "the Shared Context article"?

Comment: I already did, in the second comment. The very first commenter also posted a link to a blog about class fixtures.